# How to integrate AdminLTE into Yii2 Basic in manual way

Tags: yii2

You know, yii2 with adminlte is exist in this [git](https://github.com/dmstr/yii2-adminlte-asset) .

But if I use this using composer, it not gives me an educate. 
You know, I want to learn step by step.

So I tried like this:

1. I download adminlte in his official.
2. In this zip file, I have one folder with name : "AdminLTE: 2.*"
3. Then I Extract all the item in folder AdminLTE:2.* into vendor/bower/adminLTE/"bunch of file"

Now, I edit assets/AppAsset like this:

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle { 
   public $basePath = '@webroot';
   public $baseUrl = '@web';
   public $sourcePath = '@bower/'adminLTE';

   public $css = [
    'adminLTE/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css',
    'css/site.css',
   ];

public $js = [
       'adminLTE/dist/js/app.js'
];
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
];

}
```

But, both css and js below is 404 ?

Any help it so appreciated

Comment: please reference Yii2 starter kit with module backend for more detail about config admin lte. https://github.com/trntv/yii2-starter-kit

Answer (score 1):

If you want to manually add AdminLTE there is no need to put it in the `bower` folder.

Place it in the `/web` folder (in case of Advanced Template it's `/frontend/web` or `/backend/web`).

You have got AppAsset already set for this folder but you have to remove `$sourcePath` because when this is set `$basePath` and `$baseUrl` are overriden.

Comment: Thanks, but I used yii2 basic. Nit advance

Comment: So the folder is `/web` like I said first.

Answer (score 1):

Do not add theme inside the vendor for manual installation of theme. Follow below mentioned steps.

**Step 1 :** Download your adminlte and create a directory named theme inside a root

```
       ex. your_project/basic/themes ( i.e outside the web directory)
```

**Step 2 :** paste your adminlte theme folder inside newly created theme directory

**Step 3 :** Now you need to create asset to register all the csss and js required for adminlte theme

go to ***your_project/basic/assets*** directory and create a new file lets say, **AdminLTEAsset.php**

```
namespace app\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

/**
 * @author Qiang Xue <qiang.xue@gmail.com>
 * @since 2.0
 */
class AdminLTEAsset extends AssetBundle {

    public $sourcePath = '@app/themes/adminlte/';
    public $css = [
        'dist/css/AdminLTE.css',
        'font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css',
        'dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css',
        ];
    public $js = [
        'dist/js/app.js',
        'plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
        'plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js',
        'dist/js/demo.js',
        ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    ];
}
```

Step 4: Now go to the ***themes/adminlte/layouts/main.php*** and register your newly created **AdminLTEAsset**. as follows.

```
$assets = app\assets\AdminLTEAsset::register($this);
$basUrl = $assets->baseUrl;
```

Step 5 : in your ***/config/web.php*** file add the following pathmap

```
'components'=>[
 'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/adminlte'],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/../themes/adminlte',
            ],
        ],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Embeding admin lte theme i yii2 basic

1) create yii project using composer

sudo du
cd /var/www/html
composer create-project yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic 2.0.4

2)now create it accessible

chmod 777 -R project name

3) download admin lte theme by using

git clone https://github.com/bmsrox/baseapp-yii2basic-adminlte.git

4) now update composer

composer update

if token error then  create account in git and create token in setting tab by clicking genarate new token

copy and provide it to composer

5) update your web.php file in config

```
<?php

$params = require(__DIR__ . '/params.php');

$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => ['log'],
    'layout'=>'column2',
    'layoutPath'=>'@app/themes/adminLTE/layouts',
    'components' => [

     'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                ''=>'site/index',
                '<action:(index|login|logout)>'=>'site/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>'
            ],
        ],

         'view' => [
            'theme' => [
                'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/adminLTE'],
                'baseUrl' => '@web/../themes/adminLTE',
            ],
        ],

        'request' => [
            // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
            'cookieValidationKey' => 'n0VkMX1RmIa_ovJmwR3Gn_hdZyQ7SyKe',
        ],
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        ],
        'errorHandler' => [
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ],
        'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => true,
        ],
        'log' => [
            'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
            'targets' => [
                [
                    'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                    'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
        'db' => require(__DIR__ . '/db.php'),
    ],
    'params' => $params,
];

if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
    $config['modules']['debug'] = 'yii\debug\Module';

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    //$config['modules']['gii'] = 'yii\gii\Module';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
            'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
            'generators' => [ //here
                'crud' => [ // generator name
                    'class' => 'yii\gii\generators\crud\Generator', // generator class
                    'templates' => [ //setting for out templates
                        'custom' => '@vendor/bmsrox/yii-adminlte-crud-template', // template name => path to template
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ];
}

return $config;
```

6) update SiteController. Php in controller folder

replace actionLogout with following code

```
public function actionLogout()
    {
        Yii::$app->user->logout();

        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->user->loginUrl);
    }

    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            // change layout for error action
            if ($action->id=='login')
                 $this->layout = 'login';
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

7) if misconfiguration error then

update apche2

by using command

a2enmod rewrite

and restrart apache using

service apache2 restart

finished...........

best of luck